# Use of tab-size style (CSS) attribute seems to be being ignored - could be a browser bug, want to check before informing mailing list

Tags: html, css, firefox, browser

This is a funny question because I'm not stuck as such, just my browser (Firefox version ... lemmie check... 22.0 (WOW When did we leave version 4? I expected 5, 6 tops! When did this happen!?))

Anyway it seems that Firefox is ignoring the tab-size attribute, but Eclipse (4.2)s inbuilt browser (user-agent: Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.6+ (KHTML, like Gecko) Chromium/23.0.1271.95 Chrome/23.0.1271.95 Safari/537.6+) accepted the tab, that's why I'm a bit confused and thinking it could be a bug.

Having said that the IDEs browser seems to be a lot more forgiving (if I miss slashes and such, I don't normally 'do' HTML and browser things - in my defense) so this could be an extension of that.

Anyway here's what I'm doing:

In the body:

```
<pre style="tab-size:4;">
(stuff that definitely has tabs)
</pre>
```

Again, fine in the IDEs browser, this changed it from 8 to 4 (I'm guessing it was 8, suffice to say it's huge) removing it and adding it back in Firefox yields no difference, hence I conclude the style is being ignored.

Inspecting the element shows a section called "rules" that has an empty block called "element" marked "inline" (I've never done more than tyre-kick this feature, again not normally one for HTML at all so forgive me if this is said totally wrong, I'm trying to provide info)

There are no computed ... things, it just says "No CSS properties".

In closing, browser bug, yay or nay?

By the way I do have HTML tags and whatnot, it's a trivial but complete setup, no doctype though. Also has the monospace font changed, it doesn't look monospace, bold characters seem wider than their counterparts. This used to work in the 'olden days' (when pre meant "preserve format" and tab-size was obeyed) I'm sure

Addendum:
Searching for "firefox pre tab size" had as the first result the link found below in the answers, I want to promise I found it, I had no idea the tag was new! I assumed given the age of tabs it'd be really old. Sorry about that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Please [check the MDN documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/tab-size) on the `tab-size` property.

It is still an experimental property and as such you need to add vendor prefixes to make it work in some browsers.

Chrome accepts plain old `tab-size` without a vendor prefix, but to add Firefox and Opera support you will need to do the following:

```
tab-size:4;
-moz-tab-size:4;
-o-tab-size:4;
```

Comment: Could you please extend your answer with the "old" way of doing it (a way of doing it before this new property) for my own curiosity, as I mention in the addendum I assumed this would be a really old attribute. (shameless copy and paste of comment on the other answer, thanks none the less!)

Comment: This is the only CSS-based way to do it, and is the "old way" in that it has been around in Firefox since 4.0 by using `-moz-tab-size`. You could try the polyfill listed on [this page](http://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/t/tab-size/), but I have not tried it myself.

Comment: That's really surprising but thanks for telling me, I've learned a valuable lesson about doing-my-own-research and not assuming, I promise, thanks for the help @Winterblood, got this sorted in a quarter of an hour, I've spent more time on lesser problems!

Answer (score 2):

The `tab-size` property is still experimental according to:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/tab-size

To see the effect in Firefox, you would need to use the `-moz` prefix to the property.

Comment: Could you please extend your answer with the "old" way of doing it (a way of doing it before this new property) for my own curiosity, as I mention in the addendum I assumed this would be a really old attribute.

Comment: I couldn't upvote earlier, just passed reputation 20, thanks for telling me.